How to smooth out only this part of the mesh?
i want this part of the mesh to be smoothed out, similar to how the smooth sculpting tool works, but i only want it to apply to the selected area. I dont want to smooth out the top and bottom edge of the selected part.
How do i achieve this in this case?

For clarity, this is how i want to to look like:

I want to keep the top and bottom edges at 90 degrees.
Currently i do this manually, but i have to do this many times so a quick way woudl be awesome. :) Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

A potential solution depending on how clean your final mesh has to be is to use a Smooth modifier excluding the z-axis as shown below on the first image.

Then apply the modifier, create a loop with 'CTRL+R' and move it down all the way. Be sure to have 'Merge by distance' enabled in order not to create additional vertices (see image below on the left).
Extrude the loop newly created in the z-direction (see image on the right).

Finally remove the highlighted faces as shown here below on the left then Edge --> 'Bridge edge loop' and triangulate with CTRL+T as shown on the right.

